# I am writing an IVR using Lua and want to run xml script in between

Tags: xml, lua, freeswitch, ivr

This is the Lua code which runs IVR

```
i = 0
j = 0

while (session:ready() == true) do 


session:setAutoHangup(false);




repeat

digits = session:playAndGetDigits(1, 3, 3, 3000, "#", "/var/sipxdata/mediaserver/data/ivrscript/sampleIvrS1test/prompts/Corporate.wav", "shout://translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=en&q=This+option+is+not+valid", "\\d+"); 



  if ( digits == "1")  then

    repeat 


   digits = session:playAndGetDigits(1, 3, 3, 3000, "#", "/var/sipxdata/mediaserver/data/ivrscript/sampleIvrS1test/prompts/coral_converted.wav","shout://translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=en&q=This+option+is+not+valid", "\\d+");



  if (digits == "1")  then
    language = "de"
    session:execute("set","transfer_ringback=$${us-ring}");
    session:execute("bridge","sofia/clixxo.co.in/208@10.161.17.112");
    session:hangup();
    destroy(0);



  elseif (digits == "2")  then

    language = "de"
    session:execute("set","transfer_ringback=$${us-ring}");
    session:execute("bridge","sofia/clixxo.co.in/101@10.161.17.112");
    session:hangup();
    destroy(0);




else
    language = "de"
    session:execute("set","transfer_ringback=$${us-ring}");
    session:execute("bridge","sofia/clixxo.co.in/200@10.161.17.112");
    session:hangup();
    destroy(0);



end




until j == 2
end
until i == 5




end
```

I want to run the functionality of following xml code if digit 3 will pressed by the user. It can achieved by Lua xml Parser but I don't know how?

```
<permission>
<name>900Dialing</name>
<label>900Dialing</label>
<defaultValue>false</defaultValue>
<type>CALL</type>
<builtIn>true</builtIn>
</permission>
```

Centos already has XPAT xml Parser but I don't know how to use it?

Comment: Please indent your code properly.

Answer (score 0):

you can run a Perl script from `mod_perl` the same way as you use Lua. It's a bit bigger overhead, but you have all the goodies of Perl for you. Also the most flexible way is to use the Event Socket library and control the call from an external application. In this case, you have a much broader choice of programming languages.

Comment: I only can use the Lua because I am using this code is in Freeswitch server and that server supports either xml or lua for the IVR confiuration.